# nearPD function in Matrix package

Tags: r, matrix, covariance-matrix, eigenvalues

Does anyone know how the eigenvalues are adjusted to make a non-positive definite matrix into a positive definite matrix in Matrix package? I mean in nearPD function.

Answer (score 8):

The `nearPD` package uses the algorithm developed by [Dr. Nick Higham](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/) and others. Higham describes the algorithm here (PDF): [Higham, Nick (2002) Computing the nearest correlation matrix - a problem from finance; IMA Journal of Numerical Analysis 22, 329–343](http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/232/01/covered/MIMS_ep2006_70.pdf). In a nutshell, they are finding the "closest" (minimum difference in [Frobenuis norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html)) positive semi-definite matrix whose values are constrained to $(-1, 1)$ and $1$'s on the diagonal.

Comment: nearPD doesn't seem to be available under R 3.1 is there an alternative?

Comment: I'll try and contact Dr. Higham by e-mail, but in the interim, you can use something similar to what I describe in [this blog post](http://www.avrahamadler.com/2013/08/19/correcting-a-pseudo-correlation-matrix-to-be-positive-semidefinite/) based on "nudging" the eigenvalues.

Comment: Actually, it seems that the `nearPD` function is now part of the `Matrix` package, which should be in any install of R which includes recommended packages.

Comment: Fantastic: thanks @Avraham Good to see base incorporating useful new functions from userworld to!

Comment: BTW:  `nearPD()` was "always" (well since 2007) in the Matrix package which has been part of R as "Recommended" included in (practically) all precompiled versions of R.